# How to align to cache line GCC ldr pc-relative

Tags: gcc, arm

In ARM, GCC uses the PC-relative load is usually used to load constants into registers. The idea is that you store the constant relative to the instruction loading the constant. E.g. the following instruction can be used to load a constant from the address PC+8+offset

```
ldr r0, [pc, #offset]
```

As result, the .text segment interleaves instructions and data. The latter usually stored at the end of function's code. E.g.

```
00010860 <call_weak_fn>:
10860:       e59f3014        ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; 1087c <call_weak_fn+0x1c>
10864:       e59f2014        ldr     r2, [pc, #20]   ; 10880 <call_weak_fn+0x20>
10868:       e08f3003        add     r3, pc, r3
1086c:       e7932002        ldr     r2, [r3, r2]
10870:       e3520000        cmp     r2, #0
10874:       012fff1e        bxeq    lr
10878:       e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
1087c:       00089790        muleq   r8, r0, r7
10880:       00000074        andeq   r0, r0, r4, ror r0
```

For a research project, I would like to ensure that code and constant never reside on the same cache line (i.e. block 64 bytes aligned).
Is it possible to align the constants generated by GCC?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier if you work with the assembly output from the compiler rather than disassembled binaries. Use `gcc -S` to generate assembly output. You'll also see `.align` assembly directives that should help you.

Comment: I'm following your suggestion. Unfortunately this means that I've to patch the generated assembly with a script.